# Iterate multi-index rows and columns DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame `(1000,1000)` that has Multi-Index in rows `label_y1, label_y2` and columns `label_x1, label_x2`. I want to iterate through all the rows and columns and **set everything to zero except where the selected row and column match**. Ideally, this works for a single column and row - both with Multi-Index -, but it could also work for more than one column and row.

The DataFrame looks like:

[local](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/96f328255a68b4badfbfaa8b3122fc0620181019124146/6943167e6f854dc5c05b3a6f8e988b0820181019124146/fa9cb4) or

```
label_columns1 = ['testing','done']
label_columns2 = ['A', 'B']
label_rows1 = ['testing','done']
label_rows2 = ['A', 'B']

local = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_rows1,label_rows2]), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_columns1, label_columns2 ]))

print(local)

       testing    done   
             A  B    A  B
row1 A       1  2    3  4
     B       1  2    3  4
row2 A       1  2    3  4
     B       1  2    3  4
```

In the case of the columns I solved the problem with the following code:

```
for col in local.columns:
    if col != ('done', 'A'):
        local[col].values[:] = 0
```

This yields:

```
print(local)

       testing    done   
             A  B    A  B
row1 A       0  0    3  0
     B       0  0    3  0
row2 A       0  0    3  0
     B       0  0    3  0
```

I am doing it similarly for rows. I have also tried with `local.iterrrows()` and `loc` the rows but it does not work. Any idea on how can I do this? What I need is this:

```
print (local)

           testing    done   
             A  B    A  B
row1 A       0  0    0  0
     B       0  0    0  0
row2 A       0  0    3  0
     B       0  0    0  0
```

Comment: This solves the problem, taking as input what shared below by @zhqiat :
    `local.loc[:,~local.columns.isin([label1])] = 0` \\

    `local.loc[~local.index.isin([label2]),:] = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the similar logic (although inefficiently to pull that together)

```
import pandas as pd    
label_columns1 = ['testing','done']
label_columns2 = ['A', 'B']
label_rows1 = ['testing','done']
label_rows2 = ['A', 'B']

local = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_rows1,label_rows2]), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([label_columns1, label_columns2 ]))


for col in local.columns:
    for row in local.index:
        if col != ('done', 'A'):
            local.loc[:,col] = 0
        if row != ('done', 'A'):
            local.loc[row,:] = 0


print(local)



          testing    done   
                A  B    A  B
testing A       0  0    0  0
        B       0  0    0  0
done    A       0  0    3  0
        B       0  0    0  0
```

Additional conditions would be implemented with or /a list-like of tuples.

An alternative method would be to use the location functions in pandas to set the values of non labels as such. Additional label conditions are implemented in the list passed into the isin function.

```
local.loc[~local.index.isin([('done','A')]),:]=0
local.loc[:,~local.index.isin([('done','A')])]=0
```

Comment: This is not what I asked or need. I need to change the values in the DataFrame to zero. Except by those that match the column and row/index.

Comment: Please be a bit more clear about what you are looking to do? Also consider creating a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people along. Expected output in a toy example is also very helpful.

Comment: I have now written it how I need it. Thanks your the comment, indeed is much clearer now.

Comment: For some reason, the second option sets everything to zero, including the matching row I need. I know how .isin works, but is messing with the data.